# VBA Excel - select all rows with value in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet named "Copy" sorted by numeric values (lowest to highest) in column H.  The sheet has headers in row 1.  The lowest value in column H is 0.  I would like to find the last row that has column H equal 0 and then select the range of rows where column H equals 0 along with the header row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job

```
Sub CustomSelect()
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    Do While Range("H" & i).Value = 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("H1:H" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That's very close.  But it only selects the cells in column H, not the entire row.

Comment: Okay, here's what I changed:   Sub Zeros()
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    Dim r As Long: r = 1
    Do While Range("H" & i).Value = 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Rows(r & ":" & i - 1).Select
End Sub

Comment: How do I do a carriage return in the comments?  Everytime I hit enter it saves the comment instead of going to the next line.

Comment: you can't do it in comments, you will need to post an answer, your code (based on my mine) works, also check my edited code `Range("H1:H" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select`. Please mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with the reply

Comment: I like yours better.  Thanks

Comment: I guess I don't have enough reputation.